# SQL Server: In with and condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple query, i am using IN keyword I want to show only rows that have all the item.

Example :  i have two table  1)Video 2) Category

```
select Video.videoid, title, categoryid from Video join Category  on Video.portalid=Category.portalid where Category.CategoryId in (1,2,3)
```

This query return all the record that have category id 1 or 2 or 3 etc.
but I want to show only rows that have all those three `categoryId` values.

I tried some other way but I did not succeed yet.

Comment: please provide data sample and expected result

Comment: Assuming `categoryId` is an `int` column - how could it be 1, 2 **and** 3 at the same time?? You need to provide more info - table structures, sample data etc.

Comment: i updated information, actually i have two table video and category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to ensure 3 different categoryid.

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table1
where categoryid in (1,2,3)
group by col1, col2, col3
having count(distinct categoryid) = 3
```

(Will remove duplicated rows, hope that's not an issue.)